# django rest framwork Column 'product_id' cannot be null

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this view I want to save a record in DB when product id received with post method

```
class PeymentAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serilizer = PeymentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serilizer.is_valid():
            serilizer.save(user=request.user,
                           status=0)
            return Response("ok")
        else:
            #return Response(serilizer.errors)
             return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

with postman I'm sending this with post method :

```
{
    "product": 2
}
```

but I have this error can you please tell me why

```
(1048, "Column 'product_id' cannot be null")
```

this is my serializer :

```
# product peyment
class PeymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_product(self, obj):
        return obj.product.product_id

    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    class Meta:
        model = Peyment
        fields = [
            'product',
            'status',
            'user',
            'transfer_id',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

and it is related model :

```
class Peyment(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='product_id',
                                related_name='product_peyment')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    transfer_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerializerMethodField` is read_only field. You need to replace it with [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) to post product_id data:

```
class PeymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    class Meta:
        model = Peyment
        fields = [
            'product',
            'status',
            'user',
            'transfer_id',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

Since `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is default field for relation, you can remove explicit defination. Same for the user field:

```
class PeymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Peyment
        fields = [
            'product',
            'status',
            'user',
            'transfer_id',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```